# EXCEL VBA TO COMPARE 2 COLUMNS & DELETE DUPLICATED ROWS

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare the identical values in 2 columns and delete the duplicated rows decribed below:

```
  A   B

1 5   A 
2 6   B
3 7   C
4 5   A
5 6   A
6 7   C
```

The rows 4 & 6 in 2 columns are identical and must be deleted after running of macro. I searched on internet but could not find to delete the right rows with true mathching. The sheet after vba should be:

```
  A   B

1 5   A 
2 6   B
3 7   C
4 6   A
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please attempt this yourself and return if you experience a specific issue. SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you don't need to use VBA to perform this action.

You can use the "Remove Duplicates" function from the "Data" tab.

## Example:

I have the following:

[image]

You can see that rows 13,14,15, & 16 are duplicates when you compare both Columns A & B.

## Solution:

Highlight BOTH ENTIRE Columns A & B then run the "Remove Duplicates" function. You will be prompted with something Similar to this depending on your headers.

[image]

Ensure you have BOTH columns selected and click on the OK button.

My outcome was the following:

[image]

If you really need this to be done in VBA then I got the following code when running the Macro Recorder:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$16").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
        :=xlNo
End Sub
```

You should be able to edit that to fit your needs.

Comment: Tnx alot. The vba is what I needed except for a slight problem. It is also deleting the blank rows does it any possibility to protect them as they are?

Comment: I don't understand, Do you want it to leave blank rows when removing the duplicates? or is it that there are already a number of blank cells that it is removing? If it is the second, you can change the range so no to include the entire column but you will need to devise a way to work this range out each time if it constantly changes each time you run the code. (This should be easy to do)

Comment: The 1st one. I have some blank rows between tables (gave 1 example but more tables downwards seperated with empty rows). If I delete even the empty rows tables are becoming complicated to be checked.

Comment: I see, then you will have to assign each of the tables a range and perform this remove duplicates for each of the ranges declared.

Comment: Well seems so. Tnx for your advises really appreciated.